# Using `qt` parameter in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr-php-client and it its default request-handler is `select` there is no way to change it unless I change the code itself. however, there is the parameter `qt`. I updated `solrconfig` to include `<requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >` and I tried to use request handler name with or without `/` in `solrconfig` as well as in the url with `qt` parameter.

This link is working:`solr_server_port_index/custom?q=`

While this is not: `solr_server_port_index/select?qt=custom&q=` neither this `solr_server_port_index/select?qt=/custom&q=`

what am I missing here?

Comment: By default there is a request handler named `/select` - did you disable that as well? Did you restart / reload Solr after changing the configuration? .. and this is _really_ an issue which should be fixed in `solr-php-client` - using different request handler names than `select` is a required feature under many conditions..

Comment: I have not changed the default in `solr-php-client`. In this library, there is no option to change the path of the request handler to something other than `/select` unless you change the codes of the library. so the only option now is to use `qt`. I did the changes above and I used solr admin page to test the querying using '/select` as path and myCustomRequestHandler as `qt` parameter and just does not work. therefore the issue is not in `solr-php-client`. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Solr uses the qt parameter to determine which Query Handler should be used to process the request. Valid values are any of the names specified by  declarations in solrconfig.xml.
    if we won't specify qt parameter then there must be a request handler in solrConfig.xml for a given request.

```
        my experiments with solr 1.4 with qt parameter is mentioned below  

            <requestHandler name="/ana" class="solr.DisMaxRequestHandler" >
                  ......   
            </requestHandler>                                 
        http://url:8081/solr/select?wt=xml&q=questionDetail:question&start=0&rows=10&qt=/ana  
        working fine  
        http://url:8081/solr/ana?wt=xml&q=questionDetail:question&start=0&rows=10  
        working fine  
         http://anaplatha.99.jsb9.net:8081/solr/select?wt=xml&q=questionDetail:question&start=0&rows=10&qt=\ana     
        error : HTTP Status 400 - unknown handler: \ana(this error I am getting for any value of qt which is  != /ana)    


references ::  
  https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreQueryParameters  
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3161
```

Comment: Solr 1.4 is way too old to say anything useful about this, as this behaviour has changed since then.

Comment: Thanks @ MatsLindh , kindly let us know on which Solr version qt support is deprecated(or totally stopped).

Comment: @sami-al-subhi kindly let me know on which solr version you are working & also share your solrconfig.xml request handler entries for custom request handler

Comment: The `qt` parameter is still supported, but the default values for the RequestDispatcher changed in 3.6 -- but even that's so old that any behaviour _should_ be confirmed on at least 6.x.

Answer (score 0):

To work around the missing configurability of `solr-php-client` (I created [issue #6 to track this](https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client/issues/6)), you can extend the Service class and override the `_constructUrl` method to detect calls to `select` - and replace it with your own request handler. Modify this example to take the request handler name as custom `->setRequestHandler` or however you want to fix it:

```
class Custom_RequestHandler_Solr extends Apache_Solr_Service {
    public function _constructUrl($servlet, $params = []) {
        if ($servlet == 'select') {
            $servlet = 'mycustomrequesthandler';
        }

        return parent::_constructUrl($servlet, $params);
    }
}
```